# Write $Δz= z- z_0$ and show that the limit as $z$ approaches $z_0$ of $f(z)=w_0$ if and only if the limit as $Δz$ approaches $0$ of $f(z_0+Δz)=w_0$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I am lost on this complex analysis question.  I know that I have to use the properties of the theorems in my text but am not sure where to even begin.  Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: It just comes down to noticing that "$a\to b$" is equivalent to "$a+c\to b+c$" where $b$ and $c$ are fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will show you how to do one direction, and hopefully you will be able to do the other.

Let us suppose that $f(z)\to f(z_0)$ as $z\to z_0$, and we will show that $f(z_0 + \Delta z) \to f(z)$ as $\Delta z\to 0$.

By our definition of limit, we are trying to show that whenever we are given $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that if $0<|z-z_0|<\delta$, then $|f(z)-f(z_0)| < \epsilon$.

We are trying to show that given $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that if $0 < |\color{blue}{\Delta z}| < \delta$, then $|f(z_0 + \color{blue}{\Delta z}) - f(z)| < \epsilon$.

If we just unpack the definition of $\Delta z$, we see that we are trying to show that given $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that if $0 < |\color{blue}{z - z_0}| < \delta$, then $|f\big(z_0 + \color{blue}{(z-z_0)}\big) - f(z)| = |f(z) - f(z_0)| < \epsilon$. We recognize this last inequality as the same one from our assumption, so the claim is proved.

Now try the other direction!